# Card flip on click, close only with close box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flip

I've set up a card flip animation.

On click, the card flips over.

The "back" side of the card has a "close box."

I want the card to flip back over only when you click the close box on the backside.

Currently, I add a class to the div with jquery, which "flips" the card.

```
$(".card").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped');

 });
```

See pen here:
https://codepen.io/dtomasch/pen/GBBMEm

I'm sure I'll beed to change "toggleClass" to "addClass" but I'm not sure how to target the closeButton and tell it to affect the card.

Edit: I forgot to mention, there are multiple instances of .card on this page, which is why I used $this instead of referencing .card directly since it would obviously flip all the cards at one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of targeting the whole of the card with a click listener, Target just the front. This way when the whole card is flipped the front of the card is now at the back allowing you to target the closeButton and clicking anywhere else in the card without being flipped  .

```
$(".front").click(function() {
    $(".card").toggleClass('flipped');
});

$(".closeButton").click(function() {
    $(".card").toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

codepen example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaaePJ

Edit: for multiple instances change to.

```
$(".front").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('flipped');
});

$(".closeButton").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

Comment: This one seemed to work best for me and I went with this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Another neat way is to use [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach a click event to the document and have a filter(selector).

```
$(document).on('click', ".card:not(.flipped)", function () { // ".card:not(.flipped)" means that if user click on .card element that doesn't have .flipped class
      $(".card").toggleClass('flipped');
  });

$(document).on('click', ".card .closeButton", function () {
      $(".card").toggleClass('flipped');
});
```

jQuery on method is bit more powerful given that you can add a click event trigger to an an element ahead of time i.e. before it appears on the document. FYI, I am not sure about whether this has performance penalties.

Live example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqqzxw

Answer (score 1):

Add a check to the `.card` listener and add the class only if it does not have the `flipped` class already. Then, add a listener to `.closeButton` to remove the `flipped` class from the `closest` `.card`. Make sure to `stopPropagation` to ensure the `closeButton` click doesn't propagate up to the `.card` listener:

```
$(".card").click(function () {
  if ($(this).hasClass('flipped')) return;
      $(this).addClass('flipped');
  });
$('.closeButton').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  $(this).closest('.card').removeClass('flipped');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First `card` click event will add only the `flipped` class if `card` doesn't have the flipped class.

`closeButton` click event will remove the `flipped` class from `card` elemnt and I use `stopPropagation` to stop click event from bubbling up and rise the `card` click.

```
$(".card").click(function () {
      if (!$(this).hasClass('flipped')) {
        $(this).addClass('flipped');
      }
  });

$('.closeButton').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation()
  $(this).closest('.card').removeClass('flipped');
})
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/malbarmawi/pen/xJJXWG)